# PySpark Uuser defined function (UDF) to create new column

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have the following table:

```
name  time  
 a     5.2
 b    10.4
 c     7.8
 d    11.2
 e     3.5
 f    6.27
 g    2.43
```

I want to create additional columns (col1, col2, col2) where col1 is > time 10, col2 is < 0 and col3 is between 0-12. How can I write a function to add all three columns?

I have tried with following UDF; but unable to go from there.

```
def UserDefinedfunction(value): 
    if value > 10: 
  return 'True' 
    else: 
  return 'False'

udf_func = udf(UserDefinedfunction, StringType())
```

Any help would be highly acknowledged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pure pyspark instead of UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types

d = [
    ("a", 5.2),
    ("b", 10.4),
    ("c", 7.8),
    ("d", 11.2),
    ("e", 3.5),
    ("f", 6.27),
    ("g", 2.43)
    
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d, ['name','time'])
df.show()

# output
+----+----+
|name|time|
+----+----+
|   a| 5.2|
|   b|10.4|
|   c| 7.8|
|   d|11.2|
|   e| 3.5|
|   f|6.27|
|   g|2.43|
+----+----+

(
    df
    .withColumn("col1", F.when(F.col("time") > 10, True).otherwise(False))
    .withColumn("col2", F.when(F.col("time") < 0, True).otherwise(False))
    .withColumn("col3", F.when(
        (
            (F.col("time") <= 12) & 
            (F.col("Time") >= 0)
            ), True).otherwise(False))
    .show()
)

# output
+----+----+-----+-----+----+
|name|time| col1| col2|col3|
+----+----+-----+-----+----+
|   a| 5.2|false|false|true|
|   b|10.4| true|false|true|
|   c| 7.8|false|false|true|
|   d|11.2| true|false|true|
|   e| 3.5|false|false|true|
|   f|6.27|false|false|true|
|   g|2.43|false|false|true|
+----+----+-----+-----+----+
```

@EDIT

If for some reason UDF are required, maybe you could do like this:

```
@F.pandas_udf(types.BooleanType())
def build_col1(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return s.apply(lambda x: x > 10)

@F.pandas_udf(types.BooleanType())
def build_col2(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return s.apply(lambda x: x < 0)

@F.pandas_udf(types.BooleanType())
def build_col3(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return s.apply(lambda x: x >= 0 and x <= 12)

(
    df
    .withColumn("col1", build_col1("time"))
    .withColumn("col2", build_col2("time"))
    .withColumn("col3", build_col3("time"))
    .show()

)

# output
+----+----+-----+-----+----+
|name|time| col1| col2|col3|
+----+----+-----+-----+----+
|   a| 5.2|false|false|true|
|   b|10.4| true|false|true|
|   c| 7.8|false|false|true|
|   d|11.2| true|false|true|
|   e| 3.5|false|false|true|
|   f|6.27|false|false|true|
|   g|2.43|false|false|true|
+----+----+-----+-----+----+
```

Comment: Thank you for this; well, my use case require UDF unfortunately.

Comment: hm, and yet you accepted the answer?

Comment: because of your effort and code may be useful to someone.

Comment: @sam see my edit, is this helpful in anyway?

Comment: Yes this works; need to remove types (types.BooleanType()). Thank you very much.